# Get html attribute value

Tags: javascript

How to get the span value through javascript. I got the below through

`document.getElementsByClassName("breadcrumb-item")[1]`

I want to get the span value. How to get it using javascript.

```
<li class="breadcrumb-item">
       <a href="@crumbUrl">
         <span>
           @Html.Raw(breadcrumb.Name)
         </span>
       </a>
    </li>
```

Comment: Why `[1]`? And what have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `querySelector` like:

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('.breadcrumb-item > a > span').innerHTML);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="breadcrumb-item">
    <a href="@crumbUrl">
      <span>
        value   <!--@Html.Raw(breadcrumb.Name)-->
      </span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Reference:

- [Document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector?retiredLocale=en)

---

If is more than 1

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.breadcrumb-item > a > span').forEach(el =>{
  console.log(el.innerHTML);
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="breadcrumb-item">
    <a href="@crumbUrl">
      <span>
        value   <!--@Html.Raw(breadcrumb.Name)-->
      </span>
    </a>
  </li>
   <li class="breadcrumb-item">
    <a href="@crumbUrl">
      <span>
        value2   <!--@Html.Raw(breadcrumb.Name)-->
      </span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Reference:

- [Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll?retiredLocale=en)
- [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?retiredLocale=en)

Comment: Why `.querySelector()` when there's a `[1]`?

Comment: He didn't mention that he wanted to select more than one. (or i didn't see ^^), add `querySelectorAll`

Comment: Yet another reason, besides the lack of research/effort, to ask for clarification instead of adding an answer that might work or not

Comment: Actually you are not all wrong...

Answer (score 1):

You can create a variable to get element:

var list = document.getElementsByClassName("breadcrumb-item")[0];

var spanVal = list.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerHTML;

console.log(spanVal);